# lit: wrap expensive dom in different tags

Tags: web-component, lit-element, lit

I have an expensive list of DOM nodes in my `<lit-parent>` component, which under a certain condition (e.g. parent element width < 500px) needs to be wrapped in another component (e.g. a gallery):

```js
render() {
    const expensive = this.vehicles.map(vehicle => html`<lit-vehicle id=${vehicle.id}?></vehicle>`);

    return this.someCondition ? html`<lit-gallery>${expensive}</lit-gallery>` : expensive;   
}
```

The problem is, every time the condition changes the list of expensive elements get's destroyed and re-created in the DOM, which causes the elements to flicker (I've tried combinations of `cache` and `repeat` neither changed the behaviour).

Instead I would like to re-use the already created DOM and just change (or remove) the wrapper.

The only way I found to somewhat make that work is to move the conditional into the wrapper element and move the `<slot></slot>` element around:

```js
render() {
    return this.somedCondition ? html`<div><slot></slot></slot>` : html`<slot></slot>`;
}
```

I don't like this solution since it introduces a lot of "useless" wrapper components. How can I reuse the partial DOM?

Comment: Don't use/let Lit manage the DOM, do it yourself with a vanilla Web Component?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, yes I could just do it without lit (or directly manipulate the DOM), but I would like to keep it simple with lit, or at least within lit (e.g. through a directive).

Comment: Like React, Lit is a tool that manages the DOM for you. If the tool does something you do **not**want it to do, don't use the tool...

Comment: What is this advice, I want Lit to manage the DOM, I just want it to reuse it where possible and there is directives to exactly do that, like `repeat` and `cache`, it's just a matter of figuring out how to do it. Or what alternatives I have within lit. It's like saying oh your AC in the car is not working, just go get a bicycle. I *want* to use lit.

Comment: _If all you have is hammer, everything starts to look like a nail_

Comment: If the condition that shows/hides the expensive list is common then you might want to use CSS to hide the element rather than doing it with a ternary. If the condition is not that common then your current approach might work well just as is

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of litelement, and using unsafe html, the element name can be a variable.

So, you can write

```
html`<${container}>${expensive}</${container}>`
```

and set the value of *container* to "lit-gallery", or "div", depending on the condition